# Pygame buttons functionality and correcting grid select mouse function

Tags: python, button, input, grid, pygame

I've added two rectangles, red and green to the top of the following code, and for some reason my code, which otherwise worked, does not now. The grid cells should go RED when clicked, but the clicking is skewed. Can anyone advise on the problem? I have two issues:

1. An upvote to the first one to spot and point out the error, unless I get it first!
2. I also want to add text (user 1 and user 2) to the rectangles and make them clickable. On clicking, the user selects a random grid cell (which turns either red or green)

Code as follows:

```
import pygame
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
size = (350, 350)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

width=22
height=22
margin=12


grid=[]
#Loop for each row in the list
for row in range(7):
    #for each row, create a list that will represent an entire row
    grid.append([])
    #loop for each column
    for column in range(7):
        #add the number zero to the current row
        grid[row].append(0)
        #set row 1, column 5 to one
#grid[1][3]=1
#print(grid[1][3]) #this is the 2nd row and the 4th element along (0...1 row and 0...1...2....3 Column)


# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
#ALL EVENT PROCESSING SHOULD GO BELOW THIS LINE

    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True
            #************CODE ADDED HERE**********************
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #print("user clicked the screen")
            pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            #x = grid[0]
            #y=  grid[1]
            #print(pos)
            #CHANGE THE X and Y screen coordinates as in the comments above to grid coordinates
            column=pos[0]//(width+margin+50)
           row=pos[1]//(height+margin+60)
           #set the location to one (when selected by the mouse)
            grid[row][column]=1
            #print("User click ", pos, "Grid coordinates:", row+1, column+1)



     # --- Game logic should go here


    # --- Screen-clearing code goes here

  # Here, we clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
   # above this, or they will be erased with this command.

   # If you want a background image, replace this clear with blit'ing the
   # background image.
     screen.fill(BLACK)

    # --- Drawing code should go here
    #Drawing the red and Green rectangles
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED, [0,0,120,50])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN, [240,0,120,50])

    for row in range(7):
        #the column number - this refers to the number of columns it will produce. 2, for example, will produce only 2 columns
        for column in range(7):
            color = WHITE
            if grid[row][column] ==1:
                color = RED
                #****MOVING THE REST OF THE GRID DOWN*****
                #the 60 is the margin from the top
                #the 50 is the margin from the left
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[(margin + width) * column + margin+50, (margin + height) * row + margin+60,width,height])

#*******PRINTING TEXT TO THE SCREEN**********
    # Select the font to use, size, bold, italics
    #font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
    #text = font.render("a", True, BLACK)
    # Put the image of the text on the screen at 250x250
    #screen.blit(text, [25, 25])

    # --- This bit updates the screen with what we've drawn.
pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
clock.tick(60)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What is the +50 and +60 for when you calculate the row and column?

Comment: BTW: you can do `x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()` and code will be more readable.

Comment: if you draw rectangle using `x = (margin + width) * column + margin+50` then `column = (x - (margin+50))//(margin + width)`

Comment: better create class Button and it will be easier to use it. See [button-hover](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-hover)

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means an ideal way to achieve your goal, but I tried to keep the code as consistent with yours as possible. Let me know if you have any questions about how this works. I will do my best to answer quickly.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

# first we define some constants
# doing this will reduce the amount of 'magic' numbers throughout the code
WINWIDTH = 350
WINHEIGHT = 350
WINSIZE = (WINWIDTH, WINHEIGHT)

CELLWIDTH = 22
CELLHEIGHT = 22
CELLSIZE = (CELLWIDTH, CELLHEIGHT)

CELLMARGINX = 12 # number of pixels to the left and right of each cell
CELLMARGINY = 12 # number of pixels to the top and bottom of each cell

SCREENPADX = 60 # number of pixels between the GRID and the left and right of the window
SCREENPADY = 70 # number of pixels between the GRID and the top and bottom of the window

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

DONE = False # is our program finished running?

# information about the two buttons (red and green)
REDBUTTON = (0, 0, 120, 50)
GREENBUTTON = (240, 0, 120, 50)

# create the WINDOW and CLOCK
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode(WINSIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption('My Game')
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

CURRENTCOLOR = RED # which color is active

# setting up the GRID
# cells can be accessed by GRID[row][col] ie. GRID[3][4] is the 3rd row and 4th column
# each cell contains [x, y, color]
# where x is the x position on the screen
#       y is the y position on the screen
#       color is the current color of the cell
GRID = []
for y in range(7):
     row = []
     for x in range(7):
         row.append([x * (CELLWIDTH + CELLMARGINX) + SCREENPADX, y * (CELLHEIGHT + CELLMARGINY) + SCREENPADY, WHITE])
     GRID.append(row)

# main loop
while not DONE:

    # process all events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: # did the user click the 'x' to close the window
            DONE = True

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # get the position of the mouse
            mpos_x, mpos_y = event.pos

            # check if REDBUTTON was clicked
            button_x_min, button_y_min, button_width, button_height = REDBUTTON
            button_x_max, button_y_max = button_x_min + button_width, button_y_min + button_height
            if button_x_min <= mpos_x <= button_x_max and button_y_min <= mpos_y <= button_y_max:
                CURRENTCOLOR = RED

            # check if GREENBUTTON WAS CLICKED
            button_x_min, button_y_min, button_width, button_height = GREENBUTTON
            button_x_max, button_y_max = button_x_min + button_width, button_y_min + button_height
            if button_x_min <= mpos_x <= button_x_max and button_y_min <= mpos_y <= button_y_max:
                CURRENTCOLOR = GREEN

            # calculations for clicking cells

            mpos_x -= SCREENPADX # mouse position relative to the upper left cell
            mpos_y -= SCREENPADY # ^ same

            col = mpos_x // (CELLWIDTH + CELLMARGINX) # which cell is the mouse clicking
            row = mpos_y // (CELLHEIGHT + CELLMARGINY) # ^ same

            # make sure the user clicked on the GRID area
            if row >= 0 and col >= 0:
                try:
                    # calculate the boundaries of the cell
                    cell_x_min, cell_y_min =  col * (CELLHEIGHT + CELLMARGINY), row * (CELLWIDTH + CELLMARGINX)
                    cell_x_max = cell_x_min + CELLWIDTH
                    cell_y_max = cell_y_min + CELLHEIGHT
                    # now we will see if the user clicked the cell or the margin
                    if cell_x_min <= mpos_x <= cell_x_max and cell_y_min <= mpos_y <= cell_y_max:
                        GRID[row][col][2] = CURRENTCOLOR if event.button == 1 else WHITE
                    else:
                        # the user has clicked the margin, so we do nothing
                        pass
                except IndexError: # clicked outside of the GRID
                    pass           # we will do nothing

    # logic goes here


    # drawing
    WINDOW.fill(BLACK)

    pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, RED, REDBUTTON)
    pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, GREEN, GREENBUTTON)

    for row in GRID:
        for x, y, color in row:
            pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, color, (x, y, CELLWIDTH, CELLHEIGHT))

    pygame.display.flip()

    CLOCK.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```